# Сделать отправку смс на телефон на laravel с помощью activetrail

Tags: laravel, смс

Помогите сделать отправку смс на телефон на **Laravel** используя сервис [activetrail](https://app.activetrail.com/Public/Login.aspx).

Не получается это сделать. Может кто-то работал с данным сервисом, объясните пожалуйста.

Мой запрос:

```
        $params = array( 
        'details' => array(
            'name' => 'Deliveries',
            'name' => 'Deliveries',
            'unsubscribe_text' => 'test',
            'can_unsubscribe' => true,
            'from_name' => 'Deliveries',
            'sms_sending_profile_id' => 1,
            'content' => 'test',
        ),
        'scheduling' => array(
            'send_now' => true,
        ),
        'mobiles' => array(
            'phone_number' => '***',
        ),
    );
```

Ответ:

```
string(225) "{"details":{"name":"Deliveries","unsubscribe_text":"test","can_unsubscribe":true,"from_name":"Deliveries","sms_sending_profile_id":1,"content":"test"},"scheduling":{"send_now":true},"mobiles":{"phone_number":"***"}}" {"Message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}
```

Ссылка на доку по этому запросу, все ввожу правильно, но не получаю нужный результат: https://webapi.mymarketing.co.il/api/docs/User/Api/POST-api-smscampaign-OperationalMessage

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Где ваш код с которым есть вопросы? "Не получается" - очень расплывчато и не понятно, что уже есть и почему оно "не получается". Будьте конкретны.

Comment: Добавил больше описания

Answer (score 0):

```
 $params = array( 
    'details' => array(
        'name' => 'Deliveries',
        'name' => 'Deliveries',
        'unsubscribe_text' => 'test',
        'can_unsubscribe' => true,
        'from_name' => 'Deliveries',
        'sms_sending_profile_id' => 1,
        'content' => 'test',
    ),
    'scheduling' => array(
        'send_now' => true,
    ),
    'mobiles' => array(
        array('phone_number' => '***',),
    ),
);
```